# Will exporting a DataGridView to excel using microsoft excel object library work on all windows computers?

Tags: c#, datagridview, export-to-excel

I have a datagridview in c# that I'm trying to export to excel. I'm following along with this tutorial http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/hrojasara/export-datagridview-to-excel-in-C-Sharp/ and I'm having some troubles. Firstly, I can't even build it because I'm getting all of these errors (using the same code as on that website).

```
Warning 3   Task attempted to find "AxImp.exe" in two locations. 1) Under the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\" processor specific directory which is generated based on SdkToolsPath 2) The x86 specific directory under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\" which is specified by the SDKToolsPath property. You may be able to solve the problem by doing one of the following:  1) Set the "SDKToolsPath" property to the location of the Microsoft Windows SDK.    MathMunchers
Warning 4   Task could not find "AxImp.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed MathMunchers
Warning 5   The referenced component 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' could not be found.   
Warning 6   The referenced component 'Microsoft.Office.Core' could not be found.    
Warning 7   The referenced component 'VBIDE' could not be found.
```

Reading these errors its seems like I need to have some certain stuff installed on my computer and so I'm wondering if this is even a good way to write this because I want to have this application be able to export on any windows 7 machine with excel installed.

Comment: This will only work on OS which have either Excel installed or excel libraries installed.. What if the OS doesn't have excel, what you want to do in that case ?

Comment: Hmmm ok I guess what I actually want to do is just export a .csv file or something similar that can be opened in excel

Comment: You answered the question, if you'd like to submit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work on OS which have either Excel installed or excel libraries installed.. You need to think on alternative where Excel is not installed!